# How can I approach this CP task?

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, memory-management, stl

The task (from a [Bulgarian judge](https://arena.infosbg.com/#/catalog/695/problem/101773), click on "Език" to change it to English):

I am given the size of the first (S<sub>1</sub> = A) of N corals. The size of every subsequent coral (S<sub>i</sub>, where i > 1) is calculated using the formula (B*S<sub>i-1</sub> + C)%D, where A, B, C and D are some constants. I am told that Nemo is nearby the K<sup>th</sup> coral (**when the sizes of all corals are sorted in ascending order**).

What is the size of the above-mentioned K<sup>th</sup> coral ?

I will have T tests and for every one of them I will be given N, K, A, B, C and D and prompted to output the size of the K<sup>th</sup> coral.

The requirements:

1 ≤ T ≤ 3

1 ≤ K ≤ N ≤ 10<sup>7</sup>

0 ≤ A < D ≤ 10<sup>18</sup>

1 ≤ C, B*D ≤ 10<sup>18</sup>

Memory available is **64 MB**

Time limit is **1.9 sec**

The problem I have:

For the worst case scenario I will need 10<sup>7</sup>*8B which is **76 MB**.

The solution If the memory available was at least **80 MB** would be:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

using biggie = long long;

int main() {
    int t;
    std::cin >> t;
    int i, n, k, j;
    biggie a, b, c, d;
    std::vector<biggie>::iterator it_ans;
    for (i = 0; i != t; ++i) {
        std::cin >> n >> k >> a >> b >> c >> d;
        std::vector<biggie> lut{ a };
        lut.reserve(n);
        for (j = 1; j != n; ++j) {
            lut.emplace_back((b * lut.back() + c) % d);
        }
        it_ans = std::next(lut.begin(), k - 1);
        std::nth_element(lut.begin(), it_ans, lut.end());
        std::cout << *it_ans << '\n';
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**Question 1**: How can I approach this CP task given the requirements listed above ?

**Question 2**: Is it somehow possible to use [std::nth_element](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/nth_element) to solve it since I am not able to store all N elements ? I mean using [std::nth_element](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/nth_element) in a sliding window technique (If this is possible).

@ Christian Sloper

```
#include <iostream>
#include <queue>

using biggie = long long;

int main() {
    int t;
    std::cin >> t;
    int i, n, k, j, j_lim;
    biggie a, b, c, d, prev, curr;
    for (i = 0; i != t; ++i) {
        std::cin >> n >> k >> a >> b >> c >> d;
        if (k < n - k + 1) {
            std::priority_queue<biggie, std::vector<biggie>, std::less<biggie>> q;
            q.push(a);
            prev = a;
            for (j = 1; j != k; ++j) {
                curr = (b * prev + c) % d;
                q.push(curr);
                prev = curr;
            }
            for (; j != n; ++j) {
                curr = (b * prev + c) % d;
                if (curr < q.top()) {
                    q.pop();
                    q.push(curr);
                }
                prev = curr;
            }
            std::cout << q.top() << '\n';
        }
        else {
            std::priority_queue<biggie, std::vector<biggie>, std::greater<biggie>> q;
            q.push(a);
            prev = a;
            for (j = 1, j_lim = n - k + 1; j != j_lim; ++j) {
                curr = (b * prev + c) % d;
                q.push(curr);
                prev = curr;
            }
            for (; j != n; ++j) {
                curr = (b * prev + c) % d;
                if (curr > q.top()) {
                    q.pop();
                    q.push(curr);
                }
                prev = curr;
            }
            std::cout << q.top() << '\n';
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251445/discussion-on-question-by-petar-ivanov-how-can-i-approach-this-cp-task).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This gets accepted <sup>(Succeeds all 40 tests. Largest time 1.4 seconds, for a test with T=3 and D≤10^9. Largest time for a test with larger D (and thus T=1) is 0.7 seconds.)</sup>.

```
#include <iostream>

using biggie = long long;

int main() {
    int t;
    std::cin >> t;
    int i, n, k, j;
    biggie a, b, c, d;
    for (i = 0; i != t; ++i) {
        std::cin >> n >> k >> a >> b >> c >> d;
        biggie prefix = 0;
        for (int shift = d > 1000000000 ? 40 : 20; shift >= 0; shift -= 20) {
            biggie prefix_mask = ((biggie(1) << (40 - shift)) - 1) << (shift + 20);
            int count[1 << 20] = {0};
            biggie s = a;
            int rank = 0;
            for (j = 0; j != n; ++j) {
                biggie s_vs_prefix = s & prefix_mask;
                if (s_vs_prefix < prefix)
                    ++rank;
                else if (s_vs_prefix == prefix)
                    ++count[(s >> shift) & ((1 << 20) - 1)];
                s = (b * s + c) % d;
            }
            int i = -1;
            while (rank < k)
                rank += count[++i];
            prefix |= biggie(i) << shift;
        }
        std::cout << prefix << '\n';
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The result is a 60 bits number. I first determine the high 20 bits with one pass through the numbers, then the middle 20 bits in another pass, then the low 20 bits in another.

For the high 20 bits, generate all the numbers and count how often each high 20 bits pattern occurrs. After that, add up the counts until you reach K. The pattern where you reach K, that pattern covers the K-th largest number. In other words, that's the result's high 20 bits.

The middle and low 20 bits are computed similarly, except we take the by then known prefix (the high 20 bits or high+middle 40 bits) into account. As a little optimization, when D is small, I skip computing the high 20 bits. That got me from 2.1 seconds down to 1.4 seconds.

This solution is like user3386109 [described](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251445/discussion-on-question-by-petar-ivanov-how-can-i-approach-this-cp-task), except with bucket size 2^20 instead of 10^6 so I can use bit operations instead of divisions and think of bit patterns instead of ranges.

Comment: @ Kelly Bundy That's a smart one ! I have to try it with an example though.

Comment: @user3386109 What do you mean? This *is* a full solution, for *all* allowed inputs. Are you a problem setter on that site? This and your earlier comment about the origin of the 1.9 seconds limit sound like it.

Comment: @ Kelly Bundy
prefix_mask is a mask prepared in advance to extract the: 
1) leftmost 20 
2) leftmost 20 + middle 20 and 
3) all 60 bits from the current number S with, right ?
If shift = 40 I get 0 (So I can extract 60 bits out of a 60 bit number = that is the number itself that is why the mask is 0, right ?)
If shift = 20 I get 20x1 followed by 40x0 (So I can extract the leftmost 20 bits out of S)
If shift = 0 I get 40x1 followed by 20x0 (So I can extract the leftmost 20 bits + middle 20 bits out of S)

Comment: @PetarIvanov it has 1-bits in all places where `prefix` has already determined bits. That's so I can easily tell whether `s` matches the prefix. So my `s_vs_prefix = s & prefix_mask` is `s` reduced to the already determined bits.

Comment: @ Kelly Bundy
count[i] counts the occurrences of pattern i I think. Since you extract 20 bits per pass you need 2^20 buckets because i_max can be 2^20 - 1 (this is the maximum 20 bit number that you can get), right ?

Comment: @user3386109 That sounds odd. Why would someone waste time implementing multiple algorithms for the same problem when one algorithm suffices? If that was intentional, that's a bad strategy. Better just implement one algorithm to solve all cases and move on to the next problem. Anyway... How much "a lot" faster is that different algorithm for T=3, D <= 10^9?

Comment: @user3386109 I know, I got $1000 in one 20 years ago :-). But are you saying monetary prizes for having the fastest running solution for small/special cases? Where was that? I don't know such a competition.

Comment: @ Kelly Bundy
if (s_vs_prefix < prefix) -> If your pattern is before the pattern you are looking for
++rank; -> you jump to the next bucket, right ?
else if (s_vs_prefix == prefix) -> If It is equal to the pattern you are looking for
++count[(s >> shift) & ((1 << 20) - 1)]; -> Since S can be a 60 bit number and your buckets can contain up to 20 bits you cut shift number of bits from S and extract 20 bits from the rest of S, right ?

Comment: @PetarIvanov Think of having not just 2^20 buckets but of having 2^20 + 2 buckets. One extra for all s-values below the range represented by prefix, and one extra for all s-values above that range. The `++rank` is for counting all s-values in that "below bucket".

Comment: @ Kelly Bundy Ok got it but which bucket will count the ones above the range since the array count counts the ones equal to the range and rank below that range ?

Comment: @PetarIvanov We don't need to count the ones above the range. We already know the k-th smallest s is *in* the range. I only mentioned that extra bucket above for a complete picture.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251452/discussion-between-petar-ivanov-and-kelly-bundy).

Answer (score 2):

For the memory constraint you hit:

```
(B*Si-1 + C)%D
```

requires only the value (Si-2) before itself. So you can compute them in pairs, to use only 1/2 of total you need. This only needs indexing even values and iterating once for odd values. So you can just use half-length LUT and compute the odd value in-flight. Modern CPUs are fast enough to do extra calculations like these.

```
std::vector<biggie> lut{ a_i,a_i_2,a_i_4,... };
a_i_3=computeOddFromEven(lut[1]);
```

You can make a longer stride like 4,8 too. If dataset is large, RAM latency is big. So it's like having checkpoints in whole data search space to balance between memory and core usage. 1000-distance checkpoints would put a lot of cpu cycles into re-calculations but then the array would fit CPU's L2/L1 cache which is not bad. When sorting, the maximum re-calc iteration per element would be n=1000 now. O(1000 x size) maybe it's a big constant but maybe somehow optimizable by compiler if some constants really `const`?

---

If CPU performance becomes problem again:

- write a compiling function that writes your source code with all the "constant" given by user to a string
- compile the code using command-line (assuming target computer has some accessible from command line like g++ from main program)
- run it and get results

Compiler should enable more speed/memory optimizations when those are really constant in compile-time rather than depending on `std::cin`.

---

If you really need to add a hard-limit to the RAM usage, then implement a simple cache with the backing-store as your heavy computations with brute-force O(N^2) (or O(L x N) with checkpoints every L elements as in first method where L=2 or 4, or ...).

Here's a sample direct-mapped cache with 8M long-long value space:

```
int main()
{
    std::vector<long long> checkpoints = { 
           a_0, a_16, a_32,...
    };
    auto cacheReadMissFunction = [&](int key){
        // your pure computational algorithm here, helper meant to show variable 
        long long result = checkpoints[key/16];  
        for(key - key%16 times)
            result = iterate(result);
        return result;
    };
    auto cacheWriteMissFunction = [&](int key, long long value){
        /* not useful for your algorithm as it doesn't change behavior per element */
        // backing_store[key] = value;
    };    

    // due to special optimizations, size has to be 2^k
    int cacheSize = 1024*1024*8;
    DirectMappedCache<int, long long> cache(cacheSize,cacheReadMissFunction,cacheWriteMissFunction);
    std::cout << cache.get(20)<<std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

If you use a cache-friendly sorting-algorithm, a direct cache access would make a lot of re-use for nearly all the elements in comparisons if you fill the output buffer/terminal with elements one by one by following something like a bitonic-sort-path (that is known in compile-time). If that doesn't work, then you can try accessing files as a "backing-store" of cache for sorting whole array at once. Is file system prohibited for use? Then the online-compiling method above won't work either.

Implementation of a direct mapped cache (don't forget to call `flush()` after your algorithm finishes, if you use any `cache.set()` method):

```
#ifndef DIRECTMAPPEDCACHE_H_
#define DIRECTMAPPEDCACHE_H_

#include<vector>
#include<functional>
#include<mutex>
#include<iostream>

/* Direct-mapped cache implementation
 * Only usable for integer type keys in range [0,maxPositive-1]
 *
 * CacheKey: type of key (only integers: int, char, size_t)
 * CacheValue: type of value that is bound to key (same as above)
 */
template<   typename CacheKey, typename CacheValue>
class DirectMappedCache
{
public:
    // allocates buffers for numElements number of cache slots/lanes
    // readMiss:    cache-miss for read operations. User needs to give this function
    //              to let the cache automatically get data from backing-store
    //              example: [&](MyClass key){ return redis.get(key); }
    //              takes a CacheKey as key, returns CacheValue as value
    // writeMiss:   cache-miss for write operations. User needs to give this function
    //              to let the cache automatically set data to backing-store
    //              example: [&](MyClass key, MyAnotherClass value){ redis.set(key,value); }
    //              takes a CacheKey as key and CacheValue as value
    // numElements: has to be integer-power of 2 (e.g. 2,4,8,16,...)
    DirectMappedCache(CacheKey numElements,
                const std::function<CacheValue(CacheKey)> & readMiss,
                const std::function<void(CacheKey,CacheValue)> & writeMiss):size(numElements),sizeM1(numElements-1),loadData(readMiss),saveData(writeMiss)
    {
        // initialize buffers
        for(size_t i=0;i<numElements;i++)
        {
            valueBuffer.push_back(CacheValue());
            isEditedBuffer.push_back(0);
            keyBuffer.push_back(CacheKey()-1);// mapping of 0+ allowed
        }
    }



    // get element from cache
    // if cache doesn't find it in buffers,
    // then cache gets data from backing-store
    // then returns the result to user
    // then cache is available from RAM on next get/set access with same key
    inline
    const CacheValue get(const CacheKey & key)  noexcept
    {
        return accessDirect(key,nullptr);
    }

    // only syntactic difference
    inline
    const std::vector<CacheValue> getMultiple(const std::vector<CacheKey> & key)  noexcept
    {
        const int n = key.size();
        std::vector<CacheValue> result(n);

        for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            result[i]=accessDirect(key[i],nullptr);
        }
        return result;
    }


    // thread-safe but slower version of get()
    inline
    const CacheValue getThreadSafe(const CacheKey & key)  noexcept
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lg(mut);
        return accessDirect(key,nullptr);
    }

    // set element to cache
    // if cache doesn't find it in buffers,
    // then cache sets data on just cache
    // writing to backing-store only happens when
    //                  another access evicts the cache slot containing this key/value
    //                  or when cache is flushed by flush() method
    // then returns the given value back
    // then cache is available from RAM on next get/set access with same key
    inline
    void set(const CacheKey & key, const CacheValue & val) noexcept
    {
        accessDirect(key,&val,1);
    }

    // thread-safe but slower version of set()
    inline
    void setThreadSafe(const CacheKey & key, const CacheValue & val)  noexcept
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lg(mut);
        accessDirect(key,&val,1);
    }

    // use this before closing the backing-store to store the latest bits of data
    void flush()
    {
        try
        {
            std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lg(mut);
            for (size_t i=0;i<size;i++)
            {
                if (isEditedBuffer[i] == 1)
                {
                    isEditedBuffer[i]=0;
                    auto oldKey = keyBuffer[i];
                    auto oldValue = valueBuffer[i];
                    saveData(oldKey,oldValue);
                }
            }
        }catch(std::exception &ex){ std::cout<<ex.what()<<std::endl; }
    }

    // direct mapped access
    // opType=0: get
    // opType=1: set
    CacheValue const accessDirect(const CacheKey & key,const CacheValue * value, const bool opType = 0)
    {

        // find tag mapped to the key
        CacheKey tag = key & sizeM1;

        // compare keys
        if(keyBuffer[tag] == key)
        {
            // cache-hit

            // "set"
            if(opType == 1)
            {
                isEditedBuffer[tag]=1;
                valueBuffer[tag]=*value;
            }

            // cache hit value
            return valueBuffer[tag];
        }
        else // cache-miss
        {
            CacheValue oldValue = valueBuffer[tag];
            CacheKey oldKey = keyBuffer[tag];

            // eviction algorithm start
            if(isEditedBuffer[tag] == 1)
            {
                // if it is "get"
                if(opType==0)
                {
                    isEditedBuffer[tag]=0;
                }

                saveData(oldKey,oldValue);

                // "get"
                if(opType==0)
                {
                    const CacheValue && loadedData = loadData(key);
                    valueBuffer[tag]=loadedData;
                    keyBuffer[tag]=key;
                    return loadedData;
                }
                else /* "set" */
                {
                    valueBuffer[tag]=*value;
                    keyBuffer[tag]=key;
                    return *value;
                }
            }
            else // not edited
            {
                // "set"
                if(opType == 1)
                {
                    isEditedBuffer[tag]=1;
                }

                // "get"
                if(opType == 0)
                {
                    const CacheValue && loadedData = loadData(key);
                    valueBuffer[tag]=loadedData;
                    keyBuffer[tag]=key;
                    return loadedData;
                }
                else // "set"
                {
                    valueBuffer[tag]=*value;
                    keyBuffer[tag]=key;
                    return *value;
                }
            }

        }
    }


private:
    const CacheKey size;
    const CacheKey sizeM1;
    std::mutex mut;

    std::vector<CacheValue> valueBuffer;
    std::vector<unsigned char> isEditedBuffer;
    std::vector<CacheKey> keyBuffer;
    const std::function<CacheValue(CacheKey)>  loadData;
    const std::function<void(CacheKey,CacheValue)>  saveData;

};


#endif /* DIRECTMAPPEDCACHE_H_ */
```

Comment: Using your idea I will fit in the memory requirement but how I am supposed to sort the sequence since I do not have all the elements ?

Comment: If you had a cache, you could write ```cache.get(i)``` to all the places in the sorting algorithm or just compute a bitonic sort path for every element and use that path to sort one by one or two by two to fill the output. I.E. compare to cache.get(nextPathIndex), then compare to cache.get(nextPathIndex2), ... until you get the right value and put it on output. A simple cache, maybe even direct-mapped like above, can do it fast if the sorting algorithm is cache-friendly.

Comment: I do not think that O(N^2), where N can be 10^7 will get the job done ;/

Comment: @PetarIvanov if you keep a fixed array of checkpoints, like 1 per 1000 elements / or every 1000th element, then you limit the re-computation to only 1000-iterations per cache-miss (and a big cache would reduce the misses a lot).

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this problem using a Max-heap.

1. Insert the first k elements into the max-heap.  The largest element of these k will now be at the root.
2. For each remaining element `e`:
   Compare `e` to the `root`.
   If `e` is larger than the root, discard it.
   If `e` is smaller than the `root`, remove the `root` and insert `e` into the heap structure.
3. After all elements have been processed, the k-th smallest element is at the `root`.

This method uses `O(K)` space and `O(n log n)` time.

Comment: @ Christian Sloper Can you give me a hint what to do If K is large enough so I am not able to store the first K elements ?

Comment: @PetarIvanov Then store the last N-K+1 instead.

Comment: @ Christian Sloper I implemented your idea. It gives the right answer but unfortunately It hits time limit (~ 2.2 sec > 1.9 sec) and memory limit. Even If somehow memory fits within 64 MB time will be the problem ;/

Comment: @PetarIvanov Did you already include the optimization (track the first K or the last N-K+1, depending on which is smaller)?

Comment: @ Kelly Bundy Not yet but I will.

Comment: @PetarIvanov I see you added it to the question. It doesn't really belong there. Better take it out and post it as an answer instead. (It's perfectly ok to post answers to your own questions.)

Comment: @ Kelly Bundy It's not actually an answer because it hits TL and ML. Now I tested with K or the last N-K+1 and it still doesn't fit the limits ;/

Comment: @ Kelly Bundy By the way for the last N-K+1 it doesn't produce the right answer. This logic works for the first K.

Comment: @PetarIvanov If getting accepted were a requirement for an answer, there wouldn't be answers here yet :-). I think it's an ok answer. And remember, the answers on stack overflow aren't just for the people who asked the question. Other people might have the same or a similar problem, stumble upon your question, and for them that solution might be a working answer.

Comment: @PetarIvanov It should work. Please show the code.

Comment: @ Kelly Bundy Same as in my answer. These are the only 2 lines that differ j_lim = std::min(k, n - k + 1); for (j = 1; j != j_lim; ++j) {

Comment: @PetarIvanov Well, that's not enough. For the N-K+1 case, you need to instead use a min-heap and check `> top`. I just didn't explicitly mention that because you asked for a *hint* and I figured you'd realize the rest yourself :-)

Comment: @PetarIvanov In other words, I said *last* N-K+1 but you do *first* N-K+1. The K-th-smallest value is the same as the (N-K+1)-th largest value. For example for N=10, the eighth-smallest is also the third-largest.

Comment: @ Kelly Bundy It achieves the same time ~ 2.2 sec (I edited my post) and still doesn't fit the limit ;/

Comment: @PetarIvanov But at least it fits the memory limit, right? The data should now take at most 40 MB.

Comment: @PetarIvanov You could optimize it further by using `heap` functions instead of `priority_queue`. Create a vector, reserve k spots, insert the first k numbers, then call `make_heap`. That's O(k) instead of O(k log k). Then proceed as before.

Comment: @ Kelly Bundy I will do it but first I need some clarification on your bitwise answer.

Answer (score 1):

There’s an algorithm that people often call LazySelect that I think would be perfect here.

With high probability, we make two passes. In the first pass, we save a random sample of size n much less than N. The answer will be around index (K/N)n in the sorted sample, but due to the randomness, we have to be careful. Save the values a and b at (K/N)n ± r instead, where r is the radius of the window. In the second pass, we save all of the values in [a, b], count the number of values less than a (let it be L), and select the value with index K−L if it’s in the window (otherwise, try again).

The theoretical advice on choosing n and r is fine, but I would be pragmatic here. Choose n so that you use most of the available memory; the bigger the sample, the more informative it is. Choose r fairly large as well, but not quite as aggressively due to the randomness.

C++ code below. On the online judge, it’s faster than Kelly’s (max 1.3 seconds on the T=3 tests, 0.5 on the T=1 tests).

```cpp
#include <algorithm>
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>
#include <optional>
#include <random>
#include <vector>

namespace {

class LazySelector {
public:
  static constexpr std::int32_t kTargetSampleSize = 1000;

  explicit LazySelector() { sample_.reserve(1000000); }

  void BeginFirstPass(const std::int32_t n, const std::int32_t k) {
    sample_.clear();
    mask_ = n / kTargetSampleSize;
    mask_ |= mask_ >> 1;
    mask_ |= mask_ >> 2;
    mask_ |= mask_ >> 4;
    mask_ |= mask_ >> 8;
    mask_ |= mask_ >> 16;
  }

  void FirstPass(const std::int64_t value) {
    if ((gen_() & mask_) == 0) {
      sample_.push_back(value);
    }
  }

  void BeginSecondPass(const std::int32_t n, const std::int32_t k) {
    sample_.push_back(std::numeric_limits<std::int64_t>::min());
    sample_.push_back(std::numeric_limits<std::int64_t>::max());
    const double p = static_cast<double>(sample_.size()) / n;
    const double radius = 2 * std::sqrt(sample_.size());
    const auto lower =
        sample_.begin() + std::clamp<std::int32_t>(std::floor(p * k - radius),
                                                   0, sample_.size() - 1);
    const auto upper =
        sample_.begin() + std::clamp<std::int32_t>(std::ceil(p * k + radius), 0,
                                                   sample_.size() - 1);
    std::nth_element(sample_.begin(), upper, sample_.end());
    std::nth_element(sample_.begin(), lower, upper);
    lower_ = *lower;
    upper_ = *upper;
    sample_.clear();
    less_than_lower_ = 0;
    equal_to_lower_ = 0;
    equal_to_upper_ = 0;
  }

  void SecondPass(const std::int64_t value) {
    if (value < lower_) {
      ++less_than_lower_;
    } else if (upper_ < value) {
    } else if (value == lower_) {
      ++equal_to_lower_;
    } else if (value == upper_) {
      ++equal_to_upper_;
    } else {
      sample_.push_back(value);
    }
  }

  std::optional<std::int64_t> Select(std::int32_t k) {
    if (k < less_than_lower_) {
      return std::nullopt;
    }
    k -= less_than_lower_;
    if (k < equal_to_lower_) {
      return lower_;
    }
    k -= equal_to_lower_;
    if (k < sample_.size()) {
      const auto kth = sample_.begin() + k;
      std::nth_element(sample_.begin(), kth, sample_.end());
      return *kth;
    }
    k -= sample_.size();
    if (k < equal_to_upper_) {
      return upper_;
    }
    return std::nullopt;
  }

private:
  std::default_random_engine gen_;
  std::vector<std::int64_t> sample_ = {};
  std::int32_t mask_ = 0;
  std::int64_t lower_ = std::numeric_limits<std::int64_t>::min();
  std::int64_t upper_ = std::numeric_limits<std::int64_t>::max();
  std::int32_t less_than_lower_ = 0;
  std::int32_t equal_to_lower_ = 0;
  std::int32_t equal_to_upper_ = 0;
};

} // namespace

int main() {
  int t;
  std::cin >> t;
  for (int i = t; i > 0; --i) {
    std::int32_t n;
    std::int32_t k;
    std::int64_t a;
    std::int64_t b;
    std::int64_t c;
    std::int64_t d;
    std::cin >> n >> k >> a >> b >> c >> d;
    std::optional<std::int64_t> ans = std::nullopt;
    LazySelector selector;
    do {
      {
        selector.BeginFirstPass(n, k);
        std::int64_t s = a;
        for (std::int32_t j = n; j > 0; --j) {
          selector.FirstPass(s);
          s = (b * s + c) % d;
        }
      }
      {
        selector.BeginSecondPass(n, k);
        std::int64_t s = a;
        for (std::int32_t j = n; j > 0; --j) {
          selector.SecondPass(s);
          s = (b * s + c) % d;
        }
      }
      ans = selector.Select(k - 1);
    } while (!ans);
    std::cout << *ans << '\n';
  }
}
```

Comment: @ David Eisenstat Can you please explain your answer with an example ? Let's say you have these sizes 3, 7, 6, 9, 0, 5, 1, 2, 10, 8, 3, 7 and you have to find out which is the 9th one of them (7 is the answer) how are you going to approach ?

Comment: Does it get accepted? What are the results? (I put the site's link into the question.)

Comment: @KellyBundy the fixed version does, slightly faster than yours.

Comment: Thanks. Question: Why count values equal to lower or upper separately? Because of mass duplicates?

Comment: @KellyBundy yep. The theoretical presentations of LazySelect assume distinct elements. You could also tiebreak using the array indices, not sure if that would be better (my intuition was not, but I didn't try it).

Comment: What ties/tiebreaks? What I meant was extremes like D=1, where without the lower and upper counters, everything would go into the sample vector and that would exceed the memory limit. Other than that, I don't see why you need those extra counters.

Comment: @KellyBundy right, instead of 0, 0, ..., 0 you get (0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), ..., so then you're just sampling random indices.

Comment: Hmm, I still don't see the problem. What goes wrong if you don't do that?

Comment: @KellyBundy sorry, adding indices is another solution to the problem. If you have d = 2, then yes, you will get way too many elements unless the window has open endpoints.

Comment: Ah, ok. It just clicked. I somehow thought you were talking about a different issue, not memory usage but correctness. "Tiebreaks" makes me think of deciding which **one** value to pick when there are multiple equivalent ones. Picking the correct one. Now I get it, you also meant it for keeping the sample small. Takes more memory for each value, but your sample is small so that's ok.